# CORS , REST, XMLHTTP and HTTP

Tags: rest, http, cors, xmlhttprequest

REST and CORS.. how are they different? is it even correct to compare them? because I have seen a seemingly REST API use custom X- headers to make a pre-flighted request(Docebo LMS API). This means that maybe CORS and REST are used for different purposes.. But on the surface, it seems that both are designed to give access to resources stored on a different server. Also, Simple XMLHTTP requests seem to work like HTTP.(The headers sent and received by the browser are through HTTP).. So, are XMLHTTP objects translated into HTTP by the browser? I am really taking in a ton of information right now and I cant seem to make any real progress in understanding these things... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the definition of REST and CORS on Wikipedia? Those are different technologies with different purposes. You are comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**CORS** - Cross Origin Resource Sharing. A ***concept and set of techniques*** that enables sharing of resource/data across domains. Example, from your page /yourDomain.net you try to make an ajax call to myDomain.net to post some data. Read this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) articles.

**REST** - REpresentational State Transfer. A set of **standards & guidelines** that defines a specific way for systems to talk to each other. It follows state-less http like standards where URIs reprsent resource and client can work on them using http verbs. e.g. GET weatherApp.com/weather/rome. Refer [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

**HTTP** - Hyper Text Transfer Protocol. THE standard ***protocol*** to transfer data to/from web servers. Check this [W3 specifications](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) page.

**XMLHttp** - A ***type of request*** generally used to make ajax calls from client (mainly html, javascript) applications to web servers. It works on http standards. Not bound to XML though. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).

Now, all of REST, XMLHttp, CORS work on HTTP is some way, meaning they all use the http infrastructure.

And any/all of them might be used to create a fully functional modern application. For example, a web application might use XMLHttp request to make REST service call to get some data. It can also utilize CORS to get/post data to another domain. Need not say, the whole system relies on http!

Comment: So, CORS can be used with HTTP as well as XMLHTTP...but then is it possible that accessing a REST API on a server through HTTP works but the same API Request when made through an XMLHttp object is declined? (The request is a preflighted request that uses a special "X-" header)...

Comment: @kartikeyashukla You are mixing up multiple things. Please read about the concepts first. Do NOT think too much about http. It's like the base infrastructure and believe it's always there behind all these, no matter what you do with the other stuffs. Understand, as I've said in the answer, XMLHttp works over http only. So does REST. A REST service ideally does not reject XMLHttp request, though it might be possible technically. I'd suggest, ignore the pre-flight example for now, that is a very specific example and might not be good point to start with.

Comment: Okay..thanks for the help...The thing is that my company requires me to build an android application that integrates an API. Being a noob and all, I did not go for the native route of development.. So, I used Appery.io online builder that lets me custom code in javascript with hich I have some experience... While testing the API on my dashboard, I got the desired response.. but when i tested the Application in- browser(Duh!), I got the XMLHTTP error..I guess its because the request was being made by the script... and not a browser/server..

Comment: But, these answers really made me zero-in on the problem and I used a proxy..which solved the problem..thanks again!!!

Comment: @kartikeyashukla These concepts are too vast to be discussed in detail, in SO threads! Good to know it helped you and finally you solved your problem. It's customary in stack overflow to upvote, accept answer that helped you :)

Answer (score -1):

They are totally different things.  Rest is a specifical approach to prrforming data calls.  Basically is characterized by a systen where the state is not stored on the server but rather passed in calls.  You can read more [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

Cors is a technique for enabling javascript to perform data ervice calls to domains otheir than the server donain that they came from.  Normally web browsers prevent javascript and other web technologies from doing cross origin or cross domain calls.  These are calls where a js script came from google.com lets say, and now it wats to call microsoft.com.  well the browser would stop that call because google.com and microsoft.com are different domains.

That example is obvious, so lets try a less obvious one. Your script on blogs.yoursite.com tries to call a service at shopping.yoursite.com.  now these sires are both yoursite.com but they could still be considered cross domain and usually are.  CORS allows you(on the html developer side) to say i trust these domains.  And by trusting them, now you can call their webservices even if they would have been a cross domain call.